# How to integrate best fit line in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, plot, numerical-integration

I have various lists of points that are plotted and produce graphs like this:

[image]

is there any way to integrate over the best fit line to get the area under the curve?

Comment: Are you sure you are wanting to do a _linear_ fit on the curve?  If so, do you have the _Curve Fitting Toolbox_?  Because, it provides a function _integrate()_:   "This MATLAB function integrates the cfit object fun at the points specified by the vector x, starting from x0, and returns the result in int."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `trapz` to integrate over set of discrete data: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/integration-of-numeric-data.html

Assuming your x-axes data is saved to vector `t`, and your best fit line data is saved to `fx`, then the area is easily calculated like:

```
area = trapz(t, fx);
```